# MYSQL Update column with column value

Tags: mysql, average

Need to update column average from 3 columns that contain value. This means that column without value or 0 should not be included for average. Please help. This is slightly tricky.

```
grade_tbl 
+-- prelim_g --- semi_g --- finals_g --- average_g --+ 
|     85           80          85                    |
|     82           87                                |
|     83                       84                    |
|     81                                             |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

I have this code so far:

```
UPDATE grade_tbl SET average = (SELECT AVG(prelim, semi, finals))
```

Comment: Well are the missing values zero or are they `NULL`?  You should clarify this point first.

Comment: I have checked.. its Zero (0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try the following logic, which assigns zero to missing values (which are not already zero), and also normalizes by "counting" only non `NULL`/non zero grade values in determining the average.

```sql
UPDATE grade_tbl
SET
    average = CASE WHEN (prelim_g + semi_g + finals_g) > 0
                   THEN (prelim_g + semi_g + finals_g) /
                        ( IF(prelim_g > 0, 1, 0) +
                          IF(semi_g > 0, 1, 0)   +
                          IF(finals_g > 0, 1, 0) )
                   ELSE 0 END;
```

By the way, a much better database design would be to have all grades in a single column.  Then, you could leverage the `AVG` and `COUNT` functions, which by default ignore `NULL` values.

Comment: Should add another condition if all of the 3 column is 0?

Comment: @JohnArzaga Good point, I have edited with logic which covers the case where all 3 columns might be zero.  In that case, I just update to zero.

Comment: Works as expected. I just put 0 as default.